# Kolmogorov‘s Maximal inequality and convergence a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, convergence-divergence

I have a question about Durrett exercise 2.5.12 (i).
[image]

where the (*) is given in 2.5.9

[image]

When I try to use Maximal Inequality, it is in the form of $|\frac{S_N}{a(n)}-\frac{S_m}{a(m)}|$. So that, I am not able to apply Maximal Inequality directly. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that
$$
M_n:=\frac1{a(2^n)}\max_{2^n+1\leqslant k\leqslant 2^{n+1}}\lvert S_k-S_{2^n}\rvert\to 0 \mbox{ a.s.}
$$
Indeed,
$$
\max_{2^n+1\leqslant k\leqslant 2^{n+1}}\frac{\lvert S_k\rvert}{a(k)}
\leqslant\max_{2^n+1\leqslant k\leqslant 2^{n+1}}\frac{\lvert S_k\rvert}{a(2^n)}\leqslant  
\frac{\lvert S_{2^n}\rvert}{a(2^n)}+M_n
$$

Noticing that $S_k-S_{2^n}=S_{2^n,k}$ we have by 2,5,9:
$$
\mathbb P\left(M_n>2\varepsilon\right)\leqslant \frac{\mathbb P\left(\lvert S_{2^{n+1}}-S_{2^n}\rvert>\varepsilon a(2^n)\right)}{\min_{2^n+1\leqslant k\leqslant 2^{n+1}}\mathbb P\left(\lvert  S_k-S_{2^n}\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon a(2^n)\right)}.
$$
Using boundedness of $a(2^n)/a(2^{n-1})$, we know that $\lvert S_{2^{n+1}}-S_{2^n}\rvert/ a\left(2^n\right)\to 0$ in probability.

Comment: Why boundedness of $a(2^{n})/a(2^{n-1})$ implies that $M_{n} \to 0$a.s. implies $S_{n}/a_{n} \to 0$ a.s.?

Comment: @user124697 Actually, it turns out that it was not the right place to use the assumption. I have edited.